# Why doesn't var set a global variable?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a large program that talks in Dialogflow well for GA home speakers, but adding express html support makes a test situation show talking over two functions aliases a variable. A teeny minimal example shows it with ease, and I want to fix it and know why is does the bad thing too.

So, add, set to zero and see show each a maintained value for the variable that is unfortunately two values. as if there is a 
    var HtmlCounter = 0;
    var SpeakerCounter = 0;

Obviously the desire is there is one value, etc not two. It's aliased, 'or something' !

I tried:
(*) Making a var globals = {} then appending the aliased variable.
(*) Changing the nesting of the use of the variable trying to make Dialogflow feel it owns the variable somewhat more.

```
'use strict';


// Me Daniel B Kolis
// dankolis@gmail.com

var versionNow = "03 Oct 2019 16:00";

// This is the troublesome variable
var aCounter = -1;

const functions =               require( 'firebase-functions' );
const express =                 require( 'express' );
const eapp = express();

const {WebhookClient} =         require( 'dialogflow-fulfillment' );
var bodyParser     =            require( 'body-parser' );

// Middleware
const cors =                    require( 'cors' ) ( { origin: true } );
eapp.use( cors );


// Import the service function and various response classes
const { dialogflow, actionssdk, Image, Table,   Carousel } = 
      require( 'actions-on-google' );

// Dialog flow talks to humans using google assistant
const app = dialogflow();

// Three http pages via the express package
eapp.get( '/show_counter.html', (req, res) => 
{
    let moreSeeable = "Counter is " + aCounter.toString();
    res.send( moreSeeable );
});

eapp.get( '/reset_counter.html', (req, res) => 
{
    let moreSeeable = "Acounter is this now: " + aCounter.toString() + 
                      " but right now, set to 0";
    aCounter = 0;
    res.send( moreSeeable );
});

eapp.get( '/add_counter.html', (req, res) => 
{
    let moreSeeable = "Acounter is this now: " + aCounter.toString() + 
                      " but lets add one to it";
    res.send( moreSeeable );
    aCounter = aCounter + 1;
});


// Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middleware
eapp.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ) );
eapp.use( bodyParser.json() );

// Note: This `api` must match with `/firebase.json` rewrites rule
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest( eapp );

// Start up hint if you look at logs locally or on the cloud
console.log( "VR: " + versionNow );
console.log( "First line(s) in program, sort of. Now what ?" );
console.log( "aCounter starts at: " + aCounter );

// Create I/O object for dialogs
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = 
functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
{
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    // Left part is triggered by human speech, right is the
    // function it calls
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set( 'addone', addOne );
    intentMap.set( 'questioncounter', questionCounter );
    intentMap.set( 'resetcounter', resetCounter );
    agent.handleRequest( intentMap );
});


// Three functions called by intents, a decode of speech spoken
function questionCounter ( agent ) 
{
    // Computers speak this
    agent.add( 'Counter is ' + aCounter.toString() );
}

function addOne( agent ) 
{
    let rightNow = aCounter;
    aCounter = aCounter + 1;
    agent.add( 'Counter is now ' + rightNow.toString() + 
               ' will be: ' + aCounter.toString() );
}

function resetCounter( agent ) 
{
    aCounter = 0;
    agent.add( 'Counter set to zero' );
}

// End of sad submission; last line of code
```

GOAL: That both HTML access and voice to and from speech via Dialogflow modify one value, aCounter, not two. And understand it entirely, hopefully !

Thank you greatly for your attention,
Dan Kolis

Comment: Even with the aliased value problem, if you want to use Dialogflow for talking equipment and also serve up WWW pages; (And have some intercepted and be real time), the above's useful. I do hope for an experterer person to help me. But well, I'm new to using stack overflow SERIOUSLY, maybe my explanation is not adequate...

Comment: Did I ask the question badly, or ... what ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody jumped in on this. Anyway, the answer may help somebody else ( maybe you ? )

The WWW call and Dialogflow call spawn different copies of the entire EXE in cloud processing. And this goes all the way down to even the \tmp mini file system...

The processing scope doesn't quite know the DF human and WWW human are the same, that would be impractical probably... no matter how built.

So if you think your delegated FB program is doing something it shouldn't dynamically, stop and consider if > 1 copy is in play for the specific instance that you don't grok.